Safari Produce Artifacts With react-spring Animation
On Safari while animating elements with react-swpring it provides some graphical artifacts effects.
I believe this is something related to fractional css units related to the way react-swpring works. Still looks like this is issue of Safari rendering it self.
Any way how to deal with this? Maybe this is some well known issue and is there anything to do to avoid this?
Thanks

